# How to know if the motherboard support a graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

This is my mother board:

http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/ConRoe1333-D667%20R1.0/index.it.asp

I can't find what pci-express verion it implements. I want to buy this graphics card with pci-express 2.1:

http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/5000/5450

It's a problem the different pci version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your motherboard supports PCI Express version 1.
There is no problem if the PCI Express version of your card and motherboard are different, they are backward and forward compatible so you should be fine with the card.
I used to have a very similar system like you. I had a Intel 945GZ chipset based motherboard which supported PCI Express 1 and on it I used a Nvidia 9600GT graphics card, which was PCI Express 2. Everything worked perfectly.
Your motherboard is based on Intel 945GC chipset a very similar one to mine.
The main difference between PCI express version 1 and 2 is the bandwidth. PCIe 2 offers higher bandwidth 8GB/s compared to PCIe 1 which gives 4GB/s. So if you insert a PCIe 2 card in PCIe 1 slot it will operate at a lower bandwidth. But you won't notice any performance difference with such a low end card.